# compute area of bounding box

Tags: python, geometry

I have coordinates of two bounding boxes. I want to compare them. How can I compute area of each box?

Coordinates:

```
   Box1 : 0.20212765957446807 0.145625 0.24822695035460993 0.10875
   Box2:  0.15212765957446807 0.145625 0.25822695035460993 0.8875
```

overlaping_bbox_area1/bbox_area_image_2

A quantity saying if the bboxes in avarerage are larger or small in image one than in image two.

Comment: Same way you compute the area of any other rectangle, by multiplying the width by the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bbox import BBox2D

box1 = BBox2D([0.20212765957446807, 0.145625, 0.24822695035460993, 0.10875])
box2 = BBox2D([0.6693262411347518, 0.146875, 0.31382978723404253, 0.06875])


print(box2.height * box2.width)
print(box1.height * box1.width)
```

I have found the solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
def _getArea(box):
    return (box[2] - box[0]) * (box[3] - box[1])
```

This should do the trick.
**Structure of Box:**
[xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]
This should do the trick.

Comment: why do you add 1 to the difference ?

Comment: fixed it. I was getting some problems with IOU in my scenario without adding 1. Thanks for pointing out